# Github API pagination headers with PHPLeague OAuth2 library

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, github-api

I am using this helper library [PHPLeague Github OAuth2](https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-github) to retrieve a list of repositories for an organization. I have added the `per_page=100` parameter but there are still over 100 so I need to use the pagination. There is a Link header according to the API docs, but I am not sure this library actually supports paginating results. I see in the Guzzle docs there is a `$response->getHeader('name')` method but it doesn't seem to return anything when using it on the library response.

```
/**
 * Retrieve list of organization repos from Github API.
 * https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-organization-repositories
 *
 * @return mixed|\WP_Error
 */
public function get_repos() {

    $plugin_options = Settings::get_instance()->get_settings();

    if ( empty( $plugin_options['github_token'] ) ) {
        return new \WP_Error( 'not authenticated' );
    }

    $provider = GithubAuth::get_instance()->get_provider();

    $request = $provider->getAuthenticatedRequest(
        'GET',
        GithubAuth::get_instance()->get_api_url() . '/orgs/myorg/repos?per_page=100',
        $plugin_options['github_token']
    );

    $response = $provider->getResponse( $request );
    // HERE CHECK IF THERE ARE MORE RESULTS
    return $response;

}
```

Comment: I'm ok to extend the library if that's an option

Answer (score 0):

The library author answered here https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-github/issues/6#issuecomment-234537057